# Which versions of Android and iOS does Expo cover?

Tags: react-native, expo

Is there a way to see which Android and iOS versions are catered for in the various Expo versions?

Answer (score 1):

As of Expo SDK 49 (summer 2023), Expo supports Android 5+ (API level 21) and iOS 13+.

Source: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/#support-for-android-and-ios-versions

iOS 12 support is dropped since SDK 47

Comment: The new link for the latest support is: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/#support-for-android-and-ios-versions